# get the same instance of a base class

Tags: c#, singleton

i got 2 classes:

```
public class DefaultMachineSettings : MachineSettings
{
    private static DefaultMachineSettings instance;

    private DefaultMachineSettings() { }

    public static DefaultMachineSettings getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DefaultMachineSettings();

        return instance;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance()
    {
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class Sani80100Settings : MachineSettings
{
    private static Sani80100Settings instance;

    private Sani80100Settings()
    {
        setDefaultMachineXML(true);
    }

    public static Sani80100Settings getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Sani80100Settings();
        return instance;
    }

    public void setDefaultMachineXML(Boolean overrideValue)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> defaultXML = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        defaultXML.Add("WZ1_Beschreibung", "Trennwerkzeug");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ1_Offset", "0");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ1_WirkungsbereichLinks", "2.5");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ1_WirkungsbereichRechts", "2.5");

        defaultXML.Add("WZ2_Beschreibung", "Aufzugband/Omega");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ2_Offset", "-118");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ2_WirkungsbereichLinks", "0");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ2_WirkungsbereichRechts", "0");

        defaultXML.Add("WZ3_Beschreibung", "Doppelloch Abspannung");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ3_Offset", "-250.1");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ3_WirkungsbereichLinks", "0");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ3_WirkungsbereichRechts", "0");

        defaultXML.Add("WZ4_Beschreibung", "Zusätzliche Abspannung");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ4_Offset", "-380");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ4_WirkungsbereichLinks", "0");
        defaultXML.Add("WZ4_WirkungsbereichRechts", "0");

        defaultXML.Add("Vorschub60", "100");
        defaultXML.Add("LamellenlaengeSoll60", "1998.5");
        defaultXML.Add("LamellenlaengeIst60", "2000");

        defaultXML.Add("Vorschub80", "100");
        defaultXML.Add("LamellenlaengeSoll80", "2000.5");
        defaultXML.Add("LamellenlaengeIst80", "2000");

        defaultXML.Add("Vorschub100", "100");
        defaultXML.Add("LamellenlaengeSoll100", "2003");
        defaultXML.Add("LamellenlaengeIst100", "2000");

        config.setDefaultXml(defaultXML, overrideValue);
    }
}
```

And the Base Class:

```
 public class MachineSettings : SettingsBase
{

    protected MachineSettings() : base()
    {
        ClientSettings clientSettings = ClientSettings.getInstance();

        String path = ConfigPath +  "machines\\";

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        Machine.Name machineName;

        //Hier wird überprüft, ob die SAP Maschine ein Äquivalent in Apertum hat um die gleiche Konfigurationsdatei zu verwenden. 
        switch (clientSettings.MachineName)
        {
            case Machine.Name.SANI8_10:
                machineName = Machine.Name.A7660_01;
                break;
            default:
                machineName = clientSettings.MachineName;
                break;
        }

        String fileName = machineName + "_" + Environment.UserName + ".xml";

        restoreTempConfig("machines\\" + fileName);
        config = new ConfigXml(path + fileName);

        setDefaultXML();
    }
}
```

SettingsBase

```
public abstract class SettingsBase
{
    public ConfigXml config;

    public const String CHARACTERISTIC_PREFIX = "#c#";

    private readonly static String NetworkPath = @"\\dc2\Programmdaten$\" + Environment.MachineName.ToUpper() + @"\Maschinenclient\";
    private readonly static String TempPath = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Maschinenclient\";

    public String ConfigPath;

    public static Boolean TEMPPATHSAVING = false;

    public SettingsBase()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(NetworkPath))
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(NetworkPath);
                ConfigPath = NetworkPath;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                ConfigPath = TempPath;
            }
            catch
            {
                ConfigPath = TempPath;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (WriteAccess(NetworkPath))
                ConfigPath = NetworkPath;
            else
                ConfigPath = TempPath;
        }


        if (ConfigPath == TempPath)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(TempPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(TempPath);

            TEMPPATHSAVING = true;
        }
        else
            TEMPPATHSAVING = false;
    }

    public void restoreTempConfig(String fileName)
    {
        if (ConfigPath == NetworkPath)
        {
            if (File.Exists(TempPath + fileName))
            {
                if (!File.Exists(NetworkPath + fileName))
                    File.Copy(TempPath + fileName, NetworkPath + fileName, false);

                File.Delete(TempPath + fileName);
            }
        }

    }

    private Boolean WriteAccess(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            path = path + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + Environment.MachineName.ToUpper() + Environment.UserName + ".access";
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("ACCESS GRANTED");
            }

            fileStream.Close();

            File.Delete(path);

            return true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any chance that there is only one instance of the baseclass `MachineSettings`?

That means `DefaultMachineSettings` and `Sani80100Settings` should use the same instance of `MachineSettings`

I googled a lot but didnt get a clue.

Anybody knows a solution?

greets

Comment: You seem to look for Singleton Design pattern. And it seems like you actually have done it in your `DefaultMachineSettings`. Try to apply the same pattern in your `MachineSettings`

Comment: i cant set the constructor of `MachineSettings` to private and if the code generates a new instance of `DefaultMachineSettings` there is automatically a new instance of `MachineSettings`

Comment: Two things are unclear: 1) is `SettingsBase` your own class, or is it [from `System.Configuration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase(v=vs.110).aspx)? 2) What is `config`?

Comment: i've posted `SettingsBase` class, so everything should be clear

Comment: @Thomas: Ok, so now the question is: are you sure that `DefaultMachineSettings` and `Sani80100Settings` should have a reference to the same `config` instance? If the purpose of these classes is to fill the `MachineSettings` singleton with values, then they shouldn't inherit from `MachineSettings` at all. Additionally, all the public fields in `SettingsBase` should actually be readonly properties (you don't want a random part of your app to be able to set `config` to `null` for any reason).

Comment: Thats because i want to do this. The `DefaultMachineSettings` should be accessable regardless on which machine is chosen ("Sani80100" is one machine of 10) and the `Sani80100Settings` should only be accessable if the machine "Sani80100" is selected.  But they both write on the same config.xml. My Problem was they overwrite eachother

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will use inheritance, then each instance of your `DefaultMachineSettings` or `Sani80100Settings` will inherit from it's own `MachineSettings`.

If you need to have two singleton instances (from different classes) with the same `base` instance then you need to use aggregation, not inheritance.

Something like:

```
public class FirstClass
{
    private static FirstClass instance;

    private FirstClass(BaseClass baseInstance) { /* store baseInstance somewhere */ }

    public static FirstClass getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new FirstClass(BaseClass.getInstance());

        return instance;
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    private static SecondClass instance;

    private SecondClass(BaseClass baseInstance) { /* store baseInstance somewhere */ }

    public static SecondClass getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Second(BaseClass.getInstance());

        return instance;
    }
}

public class BaseClass 
{
    private static BaseClass instance;

    private BaseClass() {}

    public static BaseClass getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new BaseClass();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Once thing that in this case you won't be able to use any `protected` members from `BaseClass`.

**Update 1**

Example with using Autofac:

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace DemoApp
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      // register your base class
      builder.RegisterType<BaseClass>() // register base class
             .AsSelf()                  // register as `BaseClass` (without any interfaces)
             .SingleInstance();         // register as a singleton

      // register all your child classes
      builder.RegisterType<FirstClass>()
             .AsSelf()                  
             .SingleInstance();
      builder.RegisterType<SecondClass>()
             .AsSelf()                  
             .SingleInstance();

      // or you can do the following
      // get the assembly
      var dataAccess = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

      // and register all classes which ends with 'Settings' as singletons
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(dataAccess)
             .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Settings"))
             .AsSelf()
             .SingleInstance();   

      Container = builder.Build();

      // The DoWorkmethod is where we'll make use
      // of our dependency injection.
      DoWork();
    }

    public static void WriteDate()
    {
        // Create the scope, resolve your FirstClass,
        // use it, then dispose of the scope.
        using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var firstClass = scope.Resolve<FirstClass>();
            firstClass.SomeMethodOrWhatever();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: ok that would work indeed. but i cant use the baseclass without storing it somewhere. a lot of developers work on this project so they need to know that they have to store the baseclass somewhere if they add a new machine

Comment: For this purpose, you can use DI container (Ninject, Autofac) and configure the bindings as singletons. In that case you won't need to store the baseclass manually - DI will care about it.

Comment: got a tutorial for this? :D

Comment: I updated the answer (I added some simple example of using autofac to DI my singletons)